# Associative arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I have this object:

```
function formBuddy()
{
    var fields = new Array();
    var labels = new Array();
    var rules = new Array();
    var count=0;

    this.addField = function(field, label, rule)
    {
        fields[count] = field;
        labels[field] = label;
        rules[field] = rule;
        count = ++count;
    }
}
```

Its used in this way:

```
var cForm=new formBuddy();
cForm.addField("c_first_name","First Name","required");
cForm.addField("c_last_name","Last Name","required");
```

The problem is, in the `addField()` function the `fields` array is being set correct (perhaps because a numerical index is being used to refer to it) but the other 2 arrays (`labels` and `rules`) aren't being touched at all. Doing a `console.log` shows them as empty in firebug.

What do I need to change to make them work? I'd still like to refer to the rules and labels by the string index of the field.

Comment: Javascript don't have native associative arrays, only objects.
Objects have properties and the name of the property is always a string. Even the index of arrays is converted to a string before the 'array magic' happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use objects instead:

```
function formBuddy()
{
    var fields = {};
    var labels = {};
    var rules = {};
    var count = 0;

    this.addField = function(field, label, rule)
    {
        fields[count] = field;
        labels[field] = label;
        rules[field] = rule;
        count++;
    }
}
```

---

But as [Christoph already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/575533/list#spacer-762632), I would store this information in a single data structure too. For example:

```
function formBuddy() {
    var fields = {};
    this.addField = function(name, label, rule) {
        fields[name] = {
            name: name,
            label: label,
            rule: rule
        };
    };
    this.getField = function(name) {
        return fields[name];
    };
}

var cForm=new formBuddy();
cForm.addField("c_first_name","First Name","required");
cForm.addField("c_last_name","Last Name","required");
alert(cForm.getField("c_last_name").label);
```

Comment: Indeed, javascript has no associative arrays. An associative array is an object.

Comment: If I did rules[field] then (where field is a string containing a field name) would it work?

Comment: Why use Objects when you can simply augment Arrays? -1.

Comment: Because he probably intended for "labels" and "rules" to be looked-up by field name instead of index?

Comment: @Luca: because it's bad practice to mis-use arrays as maps? `fields` should be an array because the keys are numeric, `labels` and `rules` should be objects if you want to use non-numeric keys; for another solution, check my answer below

Comment: @Christoph: that's right, but sometimes you need represent objects in arrays, and given the example of the question, it seems perfectly suitable.
@chakrit: They are just normal objects, you can look them up by field name.

Comment: @Luca - the data is a related set of >1 fields. That's clearly an object, and storing as such allows reuse, a robust association and the possibility of prototyping. There's a reason OO exists and we aren't all still writing C.

Comment: @annakata, why do you and other people seem to not understand that an Array is an object?

Comment: @Luca: annakata's comment referred to grouping `label` and `rule` together in a single object instead of storing them separately in different arrays

Comment: @Luca: the problem with using arrays as stores for arbitrarily named properties is that names like `splice`, `push`, ... will shadow the methods with these names; also, if you don't use any array-specific features, why should you use an array instead of a plain objects?

Answer (score 2):

`fields` should be an array, whereas `labels` and `rules` should be objects as you want to use strings as keys. Also, `addField()` is the same for each instance of `FormBuddy()` (names of constructor functions should be capitalized) and should reside in the prototype, ie

```
function FormBuddy() {
    this.fields = []; // this is the same as `new Array()`
    this.labels = {}; // this is the same as `new Object()`
    this.rules = {};
}

FormBuddy.prototype.addField = function(field, label, rule) {
    this.fields.push(field);
    this.labels[field] = label;
    this.rules[field] = rule;
};
```

You can access the labels/rules via

```
var buddy = new FormBuddy();
buddy.addField('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
alert(buddy.labels['foo']);
alert(buddy.rules.foo);
```

---

Just to further enrage Luca ;), here's another version which also dosn't encapsulate anything:

```
function FormBuddy() {
    this.fields = [];
}

FormBuddy.prototype.addField = function(id, label, rule) {
    var field = {
        id : id,
        label : label,
        rule : rule
    };

    this.fields.push(field);
    this['field ' + id] = field;
};

FormBuddy.prototype.getField = function(id) {
    return this['field ' + id];
};

var buddy = new FormBuddy();
buddy.addField('foo', 'label for foo', 'rule for foo');
```

It's similar to Gumbo's second version, but his `fields` object is merged into the `FormBuddy` instance. An array called `fields` is added instead to allow for fast iteration.

To access a field's label, rule, or id, use

```
buddy.getField('foo').label
```

To iterate over the fields, use

```
// list rules:
for(var i = 0, len = buddy.fields.length; i < len; ++i)
    document.writeln(buddy.fields[i].rule);
```

Comment: I think he/she wants the properties to be private, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Luca: I never understood why so many people are fond of these so-called 'private' variables: it's inefficient - for each instance, an additional function object holding a reference to the closure over the constructor function's variable object has to be created - and imo not 'in the spirit' of JS

Comment: @Christoph: you clearly never developed large enough applications in an object oriented environment to not be able to understand `privatization`.

Comment: @Luca: I'm quite aware of encapsulation and information hiding, but also of the concepts called over-engineering and efficiency; in JavaScript, I'd prefer exposing properties directly over implementing unnecessary getters any day

Comment: Private in JS is ridiculous - it's just not required in the way it is in build-compiled languages and wastes another few bytes of download time. Definite over-engineering 99% of the time. FWIW, I think the 'field'+ is kind of pointless, I'd just go with id alone

Comment: @annakata: dropping the prefix would enable us to get rid of `getField()`, but it might lead to naming conflicts - what about fields with ids like 'addField'? It's either using a different object as store or adding a namespace prefix; I went with the second one to add confusion to the code ;)

Comment: btw, if the ids are actual HTML ids, it might be a good idea to use '#' as prefix...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are treated as Objects in Javascript, therefore your piece of code works, it's just that firebug's `console.log` isn't showing you the "Objects" inside the array, rather just the array values ...

Use the `for(var i in obj)` to see what objects values the Array contains:

```
function formBuddy() {
    var fields = new Array();
    var labels = new Array();
    var rules = new Array();
    var count=0;

    this.addField = function(field, label, rule)
    {        
        fields[count] = field;
        labels[field] = label;
        rules[field] = rule;
        count = ++count;

        for(var i in labels) {
            console.log(labels[i]);
        }
        for(var i in rules) {
            console.log(rules[i]);
        }

        console.log(labels.c_last_name);
        // or
        console.log(labels["c_last_name"]);
    }
}

var cForm = new formBuddy();
cForm.addField("c_last_name","Last Name","required");
```

Comment: What i need to do is to be able to retreive the rule of a field. E.g rule=rules[field], or rule=rules.field. That isn't currently working with the arrays code and gives me an error.

Comment: Works for me console.log(labels["c_last_name"]); or console.log(labels.c_last_name);

Comment: you should check `hasOwnProperty()` when looping over the properties - some time ago, it was fashionable to extend `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

Is this an alternative to what you are seeking ?
Try it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
  function formBuddy() {
      this.fields = new Array();
      this.labels = new Array();
      this.rules = new Array();
      this.count=0;

      this.addField = function(field, label, rule)
      {
          this.fields[this.count] = field;
          this.labels[field] = label;
          this.rules[field] = rule;
          this.count++;
      }
  }

  var cForm = new formBuddy();

  // FILLING IN THE DATABASE
  cForm.addField("c_first_name","Diasoluka","duplicated");
  cForm.addField("c_Middle_name","Nz","inspect");
  cForm.addField("c_last_name","Luyalu","mandatory");
  cForm.addField("c_first_name","Diasoluka","duplicated");


  console.log(`ACCESSING EACH PROPERTY INDIVIDUALLY\n,${'.'.repeat(31)}`);

  let el=Object.entries(cForm.fields); // DESTRUCTURING
      console.log(Object.is(el,Object.entries(cForm.fields)));
      // false

  const [f1,f2,f3] = el; // DESTRUCTURING=DÉCOMPOSITION
  console.log("FIELDS:\n",f1," | ",f2," | ",f3,"\n\n");
  // FIELDS:
    // Array [ "0", "c_first_name" ]
    // Array [ "1", "c_Middle_name" ]
    // Array [ "2", "c_last_name" ]

  let labels = Object.entries(cForm.labels); // DESTRUCTURING
  const [l1,l2,l3] = labels; // DESTRUCTURING
  console.log("LABELS:\n",l1," | ",l2," | ",l3,"\n\n");
  // LABELS:
    // Array [ "c_first_name", "Diasoluka" ]
    // Array [ "c_Middle_name", "Nz" ]
    // Array [ "c_last_name", "Luyalu" ]

  let rules = Object.entries(cForm.rules); // DESTRUCTURING
  const [r1,r2,r3] = rules; // DESTRUCTURING
  console.log("RULES:\n",r1," | ",r2," | ",r3,"\n\n");
  // RULES:
    // Array [ "c_first_name", "duplicated" ]
    // Array [ "c_Middle_name", "inspect" ]
    // Array [ "c_last_name", "mandatory" ]


  console.log(`PAESING THE DATABASE =\nACCESSING ALL THE FIELDS AT ONCE\n,${'.'.repeat(31)}`);

  for(let key in cForm.fields){
    let el=cForm.fields[key]; // ASSIGNMENT=AFFECTATION
        console.log(Object.is(el,cForm.fields[key]));
        // true true true true

    console.log(`${el} // ${cForm.labels[el]} // ${cForm.rules[el]}\n`);
  }
  // c_first_name // Diasoluka // duplicated
  // c_Middle_name // Nz // inspect
  // c_last_name // Luyalu // mandatory
  // c_first_name // Diasoluka // duplicated


  console.log("\n");


  console.log(`THE INNER STRUCTURE OF OUR cForm OBJECT\n,${'.'.repeat(31)}`);
  console.log(Object.entries(cForm)); // DESTRUCTURING
  // (5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
    // 0: (2) ['fields', Array(4)]
    // 1: (2) ['labels', Array(0)]
    // 2: (2) ['rules', Array(0)]
    // 3: (2) ['count', 4]
    // 4: (2) ['addField', ƒ]
    // length: 5
    // [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
</script>
```

Comment: Some explanation for your code would be appreciated.